# lightning components: can helpers call other helpers

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I like to compose functions from smaller blocks.

```
helperA : function (component, param){
  //do stuff
}

helperB : function (component, params){
  //do stuff, and
  helperA(component, params)
}
```

That doesn't work. Also tried

- sticking `this.` in front of it
- passing the function helperA in as a param to helperB so that it's defined.

How do I call a function from another, either in the controller or the helper?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can definitely call another function within the same object using the `this` keyword. I just tested the following code and it works. The example doesn't make sense but it demonstrates the functionality of the code:

**Component:**

```
<aura:component >
    <input type="button" onclick="{!c.buttonClicked}" value="Click Me" id="myButton" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    buttonClicked : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.changeMyLabel(component, event.target.id);
    }
})
```

**Helper:**

```
({
    changeMyLabel : function(component, buttonId) 
    {
        var newLabel = 'My Label Changed';
        this.changeButtonLabel(component, buttonId, newLabel);  
    },
    changeButtonLabel : function(component, buttonId, newLabel)
    {
        document.getElementById(buttonId).value = newLabel;
    }
})
```