# How to use a normal Javascript function in Lightning Component?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

I'm known to using External JS library in Lightning Component but is there any way I can put a normal JS function like the on I would put in normal Visualforce such as `function toggleDiv() {...}`?

I'm getting error when I try to add `<script>...</script>` tag to Lightning Component.

Answer (score 3):

Script tag blocks are not allowed in Lightning Components as they are a security risk. You should put your code in the controller, helper, or renderer as appropriate.

Comment: Can you give me a small sample of sort, in which I can call a JS function from controller or helper or renderer into each other? IN all the samples or documentation I encountered I noticed that we can use Controller functions in some predefined syntax and are clickable from buttons etc. I guess I'm confusing a lot :-) ... I simply want to have a JS function that will find an element via a class using jQuery and operate on it to hide or show it (like a collapsible/expandable section) ...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a "normal" Javascript Function to your helper file. For example if you are on a component named "foo". You can create a fooHelper.js file and add your code:

```
toggleDiv : function(div){
    $A.util.toggleClass(div, 'classToToggle');//you don't have to use jQuery :)
}
```

And then call this inside your controller (fooController.js):

```
bar : function(component, event, helper){
    helper.toggleDiv(component.find('myDiv').getElement());
}
```

Comment: is there a way I can call a Helper function inside another helper function? Because I tried calling the function defined in helper.js and it is returning that function is not defined error in js console.

Comment: I believe you can use this.functionName(). See this : https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005FHGIA2

Comment: And this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82149/lightning-components-can-helpers-call-other-helpers

Comment: Thanks for comment here @moshe .. but I tried that and it worked fine but when I sue it to calla function recursively it freezes the browser window. Don't know why, same function runs fine in normal browser JS or visualforce page. My function looks like this: `startClock : function() { setTimeout( this.startClock() , 1000); }` also if I put Double Quotes around the function call, it does not recognize the function at all and throws error that function is not defined for this - `startClock : function() { setTimeout( "this.startClock()" , 1000); }`

Comment: Hmmm interesting, maybe ask this as it's own question. Also it seems like startClock is recursively calling itself. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes thats right,  i hid some other code for simpliciry but yes i need to call the function in Helper recursively.