# Call a helper function from within another helper function not working

Tags: lightning-experience, aura, helper

I am trying to call a helper function from within another helper function, I read on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82149/lightning-components-can-helpers-call-other-helpers) post that using `this` from within the helper function should grab the context of the object and I should be able to call the other function, but for some weird reason it doesnt work.

**mycomponentController.js**

```js
window.addEventListener('message', helper.handleEvent)
```

**mycomponentHelper.js**

```js
({
    handleEvent: function(event){
        this.otherFunction(); // This doesnt run no errors or anything
        console.log("Event handeled");
    },
    otherFunction: function(component){
        // None of this runs
        console.log("Scrolling to top of page");
        component.find('scrollerView').scrollTo('top');
    }
})
```

My best guess as to why its not working is because of the fact that I am not calling the first helper function, I am binding it to the event listener. I feel like that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

in your handleEvent, you should pass not only the event, but also the component, and
in your handleEvent method, you should pass the component reference

```
this.otherFunction(component);
```

and from whatever method where your helper is being called, you should also pass the component as a reference:

```
helper.handleEvent(component, event);
```

Comment: I edited my post sorry, it has been fixed and the problem still persist

Comment: component doesnt exist

Comment: you will have to share mycomponentController, i from there you should be passing the component and referencing the helper

Comment: Yeah, im always doing weirsd stuff, thank you though.